# Splitting the big storyboard into seperate sub-storyboards

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

I have at least 25 scenes in my Main storyboard and most of them are connected to the previous scenes. (Navigation Bar)

Now I want to migrate into child storyboards. How do I select multiple scenes and 'refactor them in storyboards'?

I can only refactor once at a time and imageviews become corrupted afterwards.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simple cmd+C and cmd+V help you. All the imageviews should be the same.

- Create new storyboard (Usually I create a new folder too)
- Copy all the swift files witch belong to scenes
- Simple Cmd+C and Cmd+V to copy ViewControllers into new storyboard.

If everything is OK, you can delete the original one.

Ps.: Dont forget to add storyboard references to reach your VCs.